Failed to Parse Configuration Class in Spring Batch with MongoDB - Missing Setup?"
 package com.example.Study.Hall.Management.controller;

import com.example.Study.Hall.Management.model.Student;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.job.builder.JobBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.RunIdIncrementer;
import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository;
import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MongoJobRepositoryFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.batch.core.step.builder.StepBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemProcessor;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.data.MongoItemWriter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.MongoDatabaseFactory;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.MongoTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.LocalDate;

@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class StudentBatchConfig {

    @Autowired
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    @Bean
    public JobRepository jobRepository(MongoTemplate mongoTemplate) throws Exception {
        MongoJobRepositoryFactoryBean factory = new MongoJobRepositoryFactoryBean();
        factory.setMongoOperations(mongoTemplate);
        return factory.getObject();  // Creates the JobRepository with MongoDB as the backend
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(MongoTemplate mongoTemplate) {
        MongoDatabaseFactory mongoDatabaseFactory = mongoTemplate.getMongoDatabaseFactory();
        return new MongoTransactionManager(mongoDatabaseFactory);  // Provides transaction management for MongoDB
    }


    @Bean
    public Job importStudentJob(JobRepository jobRepository, PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
        return new JobBuilder("importStudentJob", jobRepository)
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer()) // Optionally add a RunIdIncrementer for unique job instances
                .start(step1(jobRepository, transactionManager)) // Pass transaction manager to step1
                .build();
    }
    @Bean
    public Step step1(JobRepository jobRepository, PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
        return new StepBuilder("step1", jobRepository)
                .<Student, Student>chunk(10, transactionManager) // Updated to include transaction manager
                .reader(excelReader())
                .processor(processor())
                .writer(writer())
                .build();
    }


    @Bean
    public ItemReader<Student> excelReader() {
        return new ItemReader<Student>() {
            private XSSFWorkbook workbook;
            private int currentRow = 0;

            @Override
            public Student read() throws Exception {
                if (workbook == null) {
                    workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream("C://Users//moham//Desktop//students.xlsx"));
                }

                Row row = workbook.getSheetAt(0).getRow(currentRow++);
                if (row == null) {
                    workbook.close();
                    return null; // End of file
                }

                Student student = new Student();
                student.setName(row.getCell(0).getStringCellValue());
                student.setBloodGroup(row.getCell(1).getStringCellValue());
                student.setDateOfBirth(LocalDate.from(row.getCell(2).getLocalDateTimeCellValue()));
                student.setPhoneNumber(row.getCell(3).getStringCellValue());
                student.setExamPreparation(row.getCell(4).getStringCellValue());

                return student; // Return the populated Student object.
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemProcessor<Student, Student> processor() {
        return student -> {
            // You can add any processing logic here if needed.
            return student; // Return processed student object.
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemWriter<Student> writer() {
        MongoItemWriter<Student> writer = new MongoItemWriter<>();
        writer.setTemplate(mongoTemplate);
        writer.setCollection("students");
        return writer;
    }
}

: I'm working on a Spring Batch configuration to process data from an Excel file and insert it into a MongoDB students collection. My goal is to trigger the batch job via an API call. However, I keep encountering an error: "Failed to parse configuration class."
Here's a brief overview of what I'm trying to achieve:
API Call: I'll make an API call (code not shown here) that triggers the batch job.
Batch Processing: The batch job should fetch data from an Excel file.
MongoDB Integration: The data should then be inserted into a MongoDB students collection.
I have configured Spring Batch with MongoDB, but when I run the application, I get the "Failed to parse configuration class" error. I suspect something is missing or misconfigured in my Spring Batch setup.
Error
 Failed to parse configuration class [com.example.Study.Hall.Management.StudyHallManagementApplication]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:185) ~[spring-context-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:418) ~[spring-context-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:290) ~[spring-context-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:349) ~[spring-context-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:118) ~[spring-context-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:791) ~[spring-context-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:609) ~[spring-context-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.4.1.jar:3.4.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752) ~[spring-boot-3.4.1.jar:3.4.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:439) ~[spring-boot-3.4.1.jar:3.4.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:318) ~[spring-boot-3.4.1.jar:3.4.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1361) ~[spring-boot-3.4.1.jar:3.4.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1350) ~[spring-boot-3.4.1.jar:3.4.1]
    at com.example.Study.Hall.Management.StudyHallManagementApplication.main(StudyHallManagementApplication.java:14) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.4.1.jar:3.4.1]
Caused by: org.springframework.context.annotation.ConflictingBeanDefinitionException: Annotation-specified bean name 'studentBatchConfig' for bean class [com.example.Study.Hall.Management.controller.StudentBatchConfig] conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class [com.example.Study.Hall.Management.configurations.StudentBatchConfig]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.checkCandidate(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:361) ~[spring-context-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:288) ~[spring-context-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanAnnotationParser.parse(ComponentScanAnnotationParser.java:128) ~[spring-context-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:332) ~[spring-context-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:267) ~[spring-context-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:193) ~[spring-context-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:171) ~[spring-context-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1

]

Add the full exception you get not just a short message.

Add the full error message

Have you actually read the error, as it tells you exactly what is wrong.

Ofc I have. Why would I waste my time in pasting it in stackoverflow. Im not great in Java. This is not my area of expertise.

The error is self-explanatory. -1

You have 2 classes with the same name in different packages, which is exactly what the error is telling you. com.example.Study.Hall.Management.controller.StudentBatchConfig and com.example.Study.Hall.Management.configurations.StudentBatchConfig. Ditch the one from the controller package (as judging from the package names that is the wrong one.

Description:
A component required a bean named 'dataSource' that could not be found.
Action:
Consider defining a bean named 'dataSource' in your configuration. Other issue is solved. I'm getting this new issue. Im hard stuck. i dont know what I am missing
